# Trouble with text with gnuplot 5.2.8 on MacOSX

Tags: macos, gnuplot, homebrew

I just update gnuplot 5.x.x to 5.2.8 using brew on MacOSX Mojave 10.14.6 with the commands

```
brew uninstall gnuplot
brew install gnuplot
```

Now I have troubles with text as you can see on the picture. Dimensions of plot are also different. With the default 'qt' terminal there is no problem.

The picture is the result of

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output "test.png"
plot sin(x)
```

[image: sine function]

Comment: You appear to have changed both the version and the output terminal type. Why not just change one thing at a time... then you'd know the cause, surely?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and excuse me, I'm not sure to understand what you're saying. What do you mean by 'change the terminal type' ? I tried with 'qt' (the default one ; for some reason I don't have the 'aqua' terminal). It works. And with pngcairo and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known bug in pango/cairo libraries as distributed with brew. The only fix known at present is to downgrade to pango 1.43. See original report and various pointers to upstream trackers here: [gnuplot issue #2194](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2194/)